# Query two tables for email addresses, list each only once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables 'memberships' and 'email_list'.  Each contains an email address field.  Some may be duplicated between both tables.  I am trying to make a single list of records, but without displaying duplicates; each email only once.

Thinking DISTINCT is where I need to go, but not sure how to write the query, or if I need a join or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) query should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT email_address FROM memberships
UNION
SELECT email_address FROM email_list
```

To select multiple columns:

```sql
SELECT email_address, first_name, last_name FROM memberships
UNION
SELECT email_address, first_name, last_name FROM email_list
```

The above-mentioned query will return combined, distinct email-firstname-lastname tuples. To eliminate duplicate first and/or last names for a given email address, wrap the results in a `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT email_address, first_name, last_name FROM memberships
UNION
SELECT email_address, first_name, last_name FROM email_list
) AS temp
GROUP BY email_address
```

Comment: Awesome!  And this will avoid duplicates?  Forgot to include in original post, but if I also wanted to pull First_Name and Last_Name from tables, just add the fields as normal?  email_address, first_name, last_name?

Comment: For the uninitiated, [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) by default removes duplicates.  If you want the duplicates, you want `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @Rick: if, the email address `foo@bar.com` is present twice with different first and/or last names, you'll get two rows. In order to eliminate one of these records you need a `GROUP BY` as well. Is there a criteria about which one is kept and which one is discarded?

Comment: So, something like: SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address FROM memberships UNION SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address FROM email_list GROUP BY email_address?

Comment: Again, AWESOME!!!  Love this site and the members!!!  Thanks again to everyone that helped!!! I'd be lost without ya!

Answer (score 1):

To further take the example from @Salaman

```
SELECT email_address FROM memberships
UNION
SELECT email_address FROM email_list
```

You could then get the distinct values with something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_address FROM
(
  SELECT email_address FROM memberships
  UNION
  SELECT email_address FROM email_list
) as combined_emails
```

If your lists are not huge then this should suffice for ease of use.